# How can I cook parboiled rice in absorption method?

Tags: rice, water

How many cups of water (not liters) should I add to 1 cup of parboiled rice in case of the absorption method of cooking?

How many minutes should I cook?

Comment: Just to be clear: you're asking how much water to use for the absorption method with parboiled rice, not with jasmine or bastmati rice, correct?

Comment: Also: what KIND of parboiled rice?

Comment: @FuzzyChef, *Just to be clear: you're asking how much water to use for the absorption method with parboiled rice, not with jasmine or bastmati rice, correct?* --- Yes, correct.

Comment: @FuzzyChef, *what KIND of parboiled rice?* --- I don't know. Can you give me options?

Comment: There's parboiled bastmati rice, and parboiled brown rice, and parboiled California rice, etc.  Any kind of rice that exists can also be made/sold parboiled.

Comment: @FuzzyChef, [Check this](https://zakupy.auchan.pl/shop/auchan-ryz-parboiled.p-447630?gclid=CjwKCAjw_tWRBhAwEiwALxFPoeVibCgEiEBQUvZ1ulLFaF2pZ04qeqsu_Dy6lAidljJQbLfXdrJvxBoC7gsQAvD_BwE)

Comment: That looks like generic medium-grain parboiled rice.  Will answer accordingly, but maybe put the type of rice in your description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the amount of water to use while cooking parboiled rice is "whatever the packaging says you should use."

However, if you bought your parboiled rice in bulk or have lost the packaging, parboiled rice [is generally cooked the same way as regular rice](https://mahatmarice.com/cooking/what-is-parboiled-rice-and-how-to-cook-with-it/), but with slightly more water.  So parboiled medium-grain rice like the kind you have would use 2.25::1 ratio of water to rice by volume.  Drier rices, like basmati, would use 2::1 (non-parboiled basmati is normally 1.5::1).

Cooking times are the same as they would be for regular rice.  So for medium-grain parboiled, you could cook it like:

1. Boil 450ml of water.
2. Add in 200ml of rice
3. Cover and simmer over low heat for 15-20 minutes
4. Turn off heat and wait for another 5-10 minutes
5. Open, fluff, and serve

Like regular rice, parboiled rice can be cooked using pasta or steaming methods as well.

Comment: The packaging often doesn't give directions for absorption method at all, hence the OP's question. Their particular packaging only gave instructions for 'excess water and drain' method

Comment: Huh.  Parboiled rice out here does, but then I haven't used it much.